# time data: My column name does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am struggling with converting column of objects to "datatime".

Here is my code:

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

I got error value:

> ValueError: time data 'Order Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match)

If it converts single cells, everything works fine. I want to convert an entire column:

```
a = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[3]['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
print(a)

2019-04-12 14:38:00
```

Comment: the entire column value should match the datetime format else it throws error

Comment: Your `df['Order Date']` column has string `Order Date`

Comment: Also, "2019-04-12 14:38:00" is not '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' - if you supply a `format` it has to match the input.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find duplicated rows with column names in random places in database. I would like to tag Your answer as useful and close question as solved but i dont know how to do it with comment. I see this option only in "Answer" box.

Comment: @Jacek If you solve your question, you can post the solution as an separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `errors='coerce'` keyword to return `NaT` values where the parsing fails, identify which rows are problematic, fix them and then convert the whole column again.

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M', errors='coerce')

df[df['Order Date'].isnull()]  # identify rows with NaT values
```